# Oracle rename table to temp table, create new, then move data from temp to new table

Tags: oracle

I have a table named *MESSAGE_ID*:

```
MESSAGE_ID VARCHAR2(36 BYTE) PRIMARY KEY
DATE TIMESTAMP(6)
STATUS VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
```

I want to create a new table to add a new field which should be the primary key.

```
alter table MESSAGE_ID rename to MESSAGE_ID_OLD;


CREATE TABLE MESSAGE_ID
(
    MY_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE_ID VARCHAR2(36) NOT NULL,
    DATE TIMESTAMP,
    STATUS  VARCHAR2(200),
    PRIMARY KEY(MY_ID)
);
```

Now I want to take everything from the MESSAGE_ID_OLD and insert it into the new table, however I need to put some thing into MY_ID, some random number or something.

This is what I have, but it gives me error:

```
INSERT INTO MESSAGE_ID (MY_ID, MESSAGE_ID, DATE, STATUS)
(SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.nextval from dual), (SELECT MESSAGE_ID, DATE, STATUS FROM MESSAGE_ID_OLD));
```

Then I want to delete the old table:

```
DROP TABLE MESSAGE_ID_OLD;
```

Comment: you can also create a Trigger that will do the increment for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Insert statement you are using is not correct.

It should be

```
INSERT INTO MESSAGE_ID (
    MY_ID
    ,MESSAGE_ID
    ,DATE_t
    ,STATUS
    )
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.nextval AS my_id
    ,MESSAGE_ID
    ,DATE_t
    ,STATUS
FROM MESSAGE_ID_OLD;
```

Also, change the column "DATE" to something else meaningful, as it's a reserved keyword.